# Runtime error when attempting to delete a worksheet from a newly created workbook - Outlook VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have an Outlook macro which works to export the users `Tasklist` to an Excel spreadsheet stored on a network drive.

I am attempting to check if there is a workbook already present in the directory ([If statement taken form here](https://www.exceltip.com/files-workbook-and-worksheets-in-vba/determine-if-a-workbook-exists-using-vba-in-microsoft-excel.html)).

If there isn't one, then make a new workbook with one worksheet called "Sheet 1", and if there is already one with the correct username, then open it ([add statement taken from here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/449996-workbooks-add-only-1-sheet-visual-basic-applications.html)):

```
Dim FilePath As String
Dim TestStr As String
Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook
Dim NAME_s As String

objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
 'Use the Application Object to get the Username
 NAME_s = Environ("USERNAME")



    FilePath = "the\directory\" & NAME_s & ".xlsx"

    TestStr = ""
    On Error Resume Next
    TestStr = Dir(FilePath)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If TestStr = "" Then
    Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Add(1)
    exWb.Worksheets(1).Name = "Sheet1_old"

Else
    Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("J:\Efficiency Measures\PTaR\" & NAME_s & ".xlsx")
End If

exWb.Sheets.Add().Name = "Sheet1"
exWb.Sheets("Sheet1_old").Delete
```

When I step through the If statement, the TestStr value is firing the first condition, which is correct, but then the `exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Delete` line is triggering a runtime error (Workbook must contain at least one visible sheet). But I thought that having the `objExcel.Workbooks.Add(1)` would add a new workbook to the directory specified with one worksheet called "Sheet 1".

How do I modify the above code to ensure the new workbook generated has the "Sheet 1" name, and is saved in the nework location specified in the `FilePath` variable?

Comment: You can't delete the only sheet from the workbook - Excel doesn't "know" you're going to add one back...  Start by renaming "Sheet1" to "Sheet1_old", then add the new sheet, then delete  "Sheet1_old"

Comment: @TimWilliams - Thanks for that, but how would i then modify the above code to rename the sheet? I have updated the code above to show where I have put the name change, but it is showing up  a 438 error - Object doesn't support this property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "Sheet1Old"
exWb.Sheets.Add().Name = "Sheet1"
exWb.Sheets("Sheet1Old").Delete
```

Comment: Thanks Tim - have another issue with this particular macro which ill post in a moment - Standby! :P