# New Excel Workbook created by Outlook macro not being saved in directory

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have an Outlook macro which works to export the users `Tasklist` to an Excel spreadsheet stored on a network drive.

I am attempting to check if there is a workbook already present in the directory ([If statement taken form here](https://www.exceltip.com/files-workbook-and-worksheets-in-vba/determine-if-a-workbook-exists-using-vba-in-microsoft-excel.html)).

If there isn't one, then make a new workbook with one worksheet called "Sheet 1", and if there is already one with the correct username, then open it ([add statement taken from here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/449996-workbooks-add-only-1-sheet-visual-basic-applications.html)):

Thanks to [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44013639/runtime-error-when-attempting-to-delete-a-worksheet-from-a-newly-created-workboo), I have propery fixed the naming error I was having, but now the newly created worbook is not being saved in the directory folder. There are no errors being thrown, and the msg box at the end of the macro is being displayed correctly, so I am at a loss as to why the file isn't showing up in File Explorer.

Here is my entire program:

```
Sub Task_Grab_V2()
  Dim sKillExcel As String
  Dim strReport As String
  Dim olnameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
  Dim taskFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim tasks As Outlook.Items
  Dim tsk As Outlook.TaskItem
  Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
  Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook
  Dim sht As Excel.Worksheet
  Dim NAME_s As String
  Dim Range As Excel.Range
  Dim str As String, strClean As String
  Dim z As Integer
  Dim strMyName As String
  Dim x As Integer
  Dim y As Integer
  Dim stat_string As String
Dim r As Range, s As String, iloc As Long
Dim s1 As String, cell As Range, col As Long
Dim sChar As String
Dim strUserName As String

 objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
 'Use the Application Object to get the Username
 NAME_s = Environ("USERNAME")

 Dim FilePath As String
    Dim TestStr As String

    FilePath = "some\directory" & NAME_s & ".xlsx"

    TestStr = ""
    On Error Resume Next
    TestStr = Dir(FilePath)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If TestStr = "" Then
        Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Add(1)
        exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "Sheet1Old"
        exWb.Sheets.Add().Name = "Sheet1"
        exWb.Sheets("Sheet1Old").Delete
    Else
        Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("some\directory" & NAME_s & ".xlsx")
          exWb.Sheets.Add().Name = "Sheet1"
          exWb.Sheets("Sheet1_old").Delete
    End If




  Set olnameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set taskFolder = olnameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks)

  Set tasks = taskFolder.Items

  strReport = ""

  'Create Header
  exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1) = "Subject"
  exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2) = "Category"
  exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 3) = "Due Date"
  exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 4) = "Percent Complete"
  exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 5) = "Status"
  exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 6) = "Notes"


  y = 2

  For x = 1 To tasks.Count

       Set tsk = tasks.Item(x)

       'strReport = strReport + tsk.Subject + "; "

       'Fill in Data
       If Not tsk.Complete Then

            If tsk.Status = olTaskDeferred Then
                stat_string = "Deferred"
            End If
            If tsk.Status = olTaskInProgress Then
                stat_string = "In Progress"
            End If
            If tsk.Status = olTaskNotStarted Then
                stat_string = "Not Started"
            End If
            If tsk.Status = olTaskWaiting Then
                stat_string = "Waiting on Someone Else"
            End If




        exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(y, 1) = tsk.Subject
        exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(y, 2) = tsk.Categories
        exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(y, 3) = tsk.DueDate
        exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(y, 4) = tsk.PercentComplete
        exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(y, 5) = stat_string
        exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(y, 6) = tsk.Body

   'the following section searches the body of the task for a specified character and deletes everything after it
        col = 6   ' assumes column 6, change to your column
sChar = "#" ' assume character to look for is hash, change to yours
With objExcel.ActiveSheet
  Set r = .Range(.Cells(2, col), .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp))
End With
For Each cell In r
 s = cell.Text
 If Len(Trim(s)) > 0 Then
   iloc = InStr(1, s, sChar, vbTextCompare)
   If iloc > 1 Then
     s1 = Left(s, iloc - 1)
     cell.Value = s1
   Else
     If iloc <> 0 Then
      cell.ClearContents
     End If
   End If
 End If
Next cell
        y = y + 1
        stat_string = ""
       End If

  Next x


'Autofit all column widths
On Error Resume Next
For Each sht In objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    sht.Columns("A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    sht.Columns("B").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    sht.Columns("C").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    sht.Columns("D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    sht.Columns("E").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    sht.Columns("F").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Next sht

exWb.Save

exWb.Close

Set exWb = Nothing
'this kills the excel program from the task manager so the code will not double up on opening the application
sKillExcel = "TASKKILL /F /IM Excel.exe"
Shell sKillExcel, vbHide

MsgBox ("Tasks have been sucessfully exported.")


End Sub
```

Can anyone see why the above code would not be saving the file created?

Comment: Get rid of the `On Error Resume Next` just before `For Each sht In objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` and see what errors occur.

Comment: @YowE3K - have removed and re-run. Still no error is being thrown.

Comment: Step through the macro with `F8`. When it gets to `exWb.Save`, what happens? Also, you can specify the directory to save it in like `exWb.SaveAs "C:\WorkbookName.xls"`

Comment: add `exWb.SaveAs Filename:=FilePath` Next to `exWb.Sheets("Sheet1Old").Delete`

Comment: @BruceWayne - stepping through it sits for a sec or two then goes to the next line. Ill try specifying the filepath and see if that works.

Comment: Unrelated, but how do you *know* `TASKKILL /F /IM Excel.exe` is going to kill the right Excel.exe instance? What's wrong with `objExcel.Quit`?

Comment: It may be saving it in your temporary folder. Have you checked that? It sounds like it's saving *somewhere*

Comment: Perhaps put a `MsgBox "File saved as " & exWb.FullName` just after the `Save`, so that you can check whether it actually saved the file and, if so, where.

Comment: @0m3r - your comment worked. add it as the answer and claim your brownie points! :D

Comment: @Mat'sMug - umm, not really sure, but it worked so i didnt question it. happy to receive advice for improvements (in the correct forum of course! :P)

Comment: What is `objExcel` assigned to? Is it a visible instance?

Comment: @Mat'sMug - its just declared as `Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You need to add **`exWb.SaveAs Filename:=FilePath`** Next to **`exWb.Sheets("Sheet1Old").Delete`***

*Example*

```
    Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Add(1)
    exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "Sheet1Old"
    exWb.Sheets.Add().Name = "Sheet1"
    exWb.Sheets("Sheet1Old").Delete
    exWb.SaveAs FileName:=FilePath
```

Answer (score 2):

You're saving the workbook here:

> ```
> exWb.Save
> ```

If the workbook was created here:

> ```
> If TestStr = "" Then
>     Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Add(1)
> ```

Then you're not specifying the workbook's filename, so if it's `Book1` then you quite likely have a new `Book1.xlsx` file in your *My Documents* folder.

And if there's already a `Book1.xlsx` file, the `objExcel` instance pops an alert:

[image: A file named 'Book1.xlsx' already exists in this location. Do you want to replace it? | Yes | No | Cancel |]

<s>I need to make an assumption here, but my theory is that</s><sup>1</sup> `objExcel` is an Excel application instance that was created to "run in the background", it's not visible. But even if the app isn't visible, *normally* you'd get that alert box. Except you explicitly disabled it:

> ```
> objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
> ```

With alerts disabled, `Save` will just overwrite an existing file.

So you get no errors, but the file isn't in the folder you expected it in nor with the filename you'd save it with, but it *is* created.

If you want to *save a file under a specified path/filename*, you use the `SaveAs` method instead of `Save` - [but that's no news](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44014163/1188513).

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> [its just declared as Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application. – scb998 2 mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44013989/new-excel-workbook-created-in-outlook-not-being-saved-in-directory#comment75056254_44013989)</sub>

Comment: You are exactly right! Thank you so much for the detailed explanation of my ineptitude! XD certainly worth more than one upvote!!!